# why split() produces extra , after sets limit -1

Tags: java, regex, split

I want to split Area Code and preceding number from Telephone number without brackets so i did this.

```
String pattern = "[\\(?=\\)]";
String b = "(079)25894029".trim();
String c[] = b.split(pattern,-1);
for (int a = 0; a < c.length; a++)
    System.out.println("c[" + a + "]::->" + c[a] + "\nLength::->"+ c[a].length());
```

Output:

```
c[0]::-> Length::->0
c[1]::->079 Length::->3
c[2]::->25894029 Length::->8
```

Expected Output:

```
c[0]::->079 Length::->3
c[1]::->25894029 Length::->8
```

So my question is why `split()` produces and extra blank at the start, e.g
`[, 079, 25894029]`. Is this its behavior, or I did something go wrong here?

How can I get my expected outcome?

Comment: This behavior is not reproduced in java8 if I remember correctly - so it's most likely a bug (that got fixed).

Comment: so how can i get my expected outcome for the same problem?

Comment: You can (1) Use updated java8, or (2) Trim the first element if it's an empty string. (easy to do with a single if condition)

Comment: Well. [maybe it also reoccurs in java 8](http://ideone.com/1xpgLS)

Comment: Yes @amit so what should i do for this any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have unnecessary escaping inside your character class. Your regex is same as:

```
String pattern = "[(?=)]";
```

Now, you are getting an empty result because `(` is the very first character in the string and split at 0th position will indeed cause an empty string.

To avoid that result use this code:

```
String str = "(079)25894029";
toks = (Character.isDigit(str.charAt(0))? str:str.substring(1)).split( "[(?=)]" );
for (String tok: toks)
    System.out.printf("<<%s>>%n", tok);
```

**Output:**

```
<<079>>
<<25894029>>
```

Comment: by applying this pattern i get this c[0]::->(079 so now again i have to replace "(" with "" so it's i think it's cozy work btw thank you for answer..

Answer (score 2):

From the [Java8 Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-):

> When there is a positive-width match at the beginning of this string
>   then an empty leading substring is included at the beginning of the
>   resulting array. A zero-width match at the beginning however never
>   produces such empty leading substring.

You can check that the first character is an empty string, if yes then trim that empty string character.

Comment: i did this as u suggested but it didn't works "if (c[0].equals("")) {
   c[0] = c[0].trim();
  }"

Answer (score 1):

Your regex has problems, as does your approach - you can't solve it using your approach with any regex. The magic one-liner you seek is:

```
String[] c = b.replaceAll("^\\D+|\\D+$", "").split("\\D+");
```

This removes all leading/trailing non-digits, then splits on non-digits. This will handle many different formats and separators (try a few yourself).

See [live demo](https://ideone.com/C6ImiT) of this:

```
String b = "(079)25894029".trim();
String[] c = b.replaceAll("^\\D+|\\D+$", "").split("\\D+");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(c));
```

Producing this:

```
[079, 25894029]
```

Comment: Yes it almost works +1!! but can you explain what is \\D in your pattern?

Comment: @hiru It more than *almost* works; it does work exactly as per the requirements of your question - see link in answer. The regex `\D` means "a non-digit character". It's the opposite of `\d`, which means "a digit character".